# Compare values of two vectors

Tags: r, vector, compare

I have two vectors:

```
 a <- c(23,43,54)
 x <- c(1,543,65,89)
```

I would like to have a vector y of dimension 4 - `(dim(x))` which indicates how many values of the vector `a` are upper than each coefficient of the vector `x`.

Is there a function that does this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 colSums(outer(a, x, FUN='>'))
```

Or

```
 library(data.table)
 CJ(a,x)[,sum(V1>V2) ,V2]$V1
```